# WebService Confusion - How to get started?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, corewcf

I'm currently stuck with a very old WCF WebService, that was written about 8 years ago. None of the developers that created that thing is still available (also no documentation), therefore it's planned to set up a completely new WebService.
As far as I researched, we would still need a SOAP-Based WebService. This would be possible to do in WCF or ASMX, but ASMX seems to be obsolete since 2012, but still, there are new tutorials from last year.
So that is where my confusion starts.
What technologies can I use? Only WCF? Is ASMX really obsolete?

Additional Information: I'm a C# .Net developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can upgrade your WCF service to [CoreWCF](https://github.com/corewcf/corewcf). you can use the [dotnet upgrade assistant](https://github.com/dotnet/upgrade-assistant) for this purpose.

**References:** https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/migration-wcf-to-corewcf-upgrade-assistant/

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upgrading-a-wcf-service-to-dotnet-6/

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/

Comment: thanks, but upgrading it, is not really an opion, due to the overall miserable structure of the project and code itself. It's jsut not maintainable anymore, that's why we wanna do it fresh and correct from scratch.
Still going to take a look on the references

Answer (score 0):

You can try [soapcore](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore), wcf, [gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and Corewcf. And then see which technique is best for your situation.